# Angular datatables with promise - reload line

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatables, angular-http, angular-datatables

I'm using angular-datatables with promise and everything work's fine. I have a lot of actions that can be done on each register (using angular $http resource) like change a status or something like that.

But, I need to reload datatable's data after every action even if i've edit just one line. And this process get's a little longer!

**Is there any way to reload just the data that i've changed?** For example, if I edit some line data I want just that line to be reloaded.

Forgive me if that's not a smart question, but I need to know if I can improve the performance of the actions over the table.

Here is my code!

**DtOptions**

```
    vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromFnPromise(function() {
        vm.defer = $q.defer();
        vm.mainService.getItems(idtask, flag, type).then(function(result) 
            vm.defer.resolve(result.data);
        });
        return vm.defer.promise;
    })
    .withOption('headerCallback', function(header) {
        if (!vm.headerCompiled) {
            vm.headerCompiled = true;
            $compile(angular.element(header).contents())($scope);
        }
    })
    .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
    .withOption('createdRow', createdRow)
    .withOption('deferRender', true)
    .withDisplayLength(100)
    .withOption('initComplete', function() { });
```

**ReloadData function**

```
    function reloadData() {
        var resetPaging = false;
        vm.dtInstance.reloadData(function callback() {}, resetPaging);
    }
```

After some execution over the table, I call the function reloadData().

Thanks for any help! And I'm sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't reload the page just append the last added data to the array in ng-repeat

with simple javascript push

consider below as array to which we want add last added element. write this in "success block" so if there is confirmation of successful post then this will be added to current stack. same can be done for delete and update.

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits.push("Kiwi");\
```

Comment: If OP really uses `ng-repeat` he should avoid that and change to native dataTables rendering. `ng-repeat` is a huge bottleneck.

Comment: I don`t use ng-repeat. I use dataTables native rendering.. and i don`t know how to reach a specific line and reload it (or at least hide it).

Comment: consider this example https://codepen.io/kalaiselvan/pen/RRBzda where $scope.data is holding all data so just do the above suggestion to it while posting data.

Comment: the only thing I am trying to say is there is a variable where you store all data from the promise in that same variable while adding data you can push data to that array. which ever way you present data that does not matter as till controller it going to be the angular way.

Comment: You're in your reasoning! I get the data from the promise like this vm.defer.promise.$$state.value. Them, i can splice it, or do something and change datatable's data like this vm.dtInstance.changeData(() => { return newpromise; });

Comment: This way's much faster them reloading datatable requesting all the data again. Thank's!